# How do I get an "offset" in an AWS S3 object version listing?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is my method:

```
public function listVersionsForPath($s3Path, $bucketName, $offset, $limit) {
    $versions = array();

    $tmpS3Path = $this->cleanS3Path($s3Path);
    $fullBucketName = self::getFullBucketName($bucketName);

    $request = array(
        'Bucket' => $fullBucketName,
        'Prefix' => $tmpS3Path,
        'MaxKeys' => 100,
        'VersionIdMarker' => ???,
    );

    $iterator = $this->client->getListObjectVersionsIterator($request);

    foreach ($iterator as $object) {
        if(!isset($versions[$object['Key']])) {
            $versions[$object['Key']] = array();
        }
        $versions[$object['Key']][] = $object['VersionId'];
    }

    return $versions;
}
```

I need to limit the number of versions returned to at least 100 because I had an object with 1000+ versions that crashed PHP forthright. However, I have no idea how to skip the first 100 versions, get them out of memory, and then load the next 100.

**Finally**, I found at least somewhat of a list for all the valid options in an S3 request. If you open S3Client.php in the aws.phar, on line 184 there is a list of what AWS has as the equivalent of 'offset'. Basically, you have to grab a listing of objects and then set the offset to the value of the last key from the previous listing. I have not been able to do this myself yet, I'm using a continue; and a break; for fake pagination.

Comment: What does the documentation say about *offset*?

Comment: I can't find any reference to it. The AWS documentation is all over the place (I still haven't found a full listing of all iterator options...), but [this page](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2Faws-sdk-php%2Fguide%2Flatest%2Ffeature-iterators.html&ei=sO8nVfiNEZLjoATchoEY&usg=AFQjCNFBN5N51i1OBOYKei1cTZ45n_GLKg&sig2=8Aq0mJpZMUC1j6yA83bB4w&bvm=bv.90491159,d.cGU) is where I got `page_size` and `limit` from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get an offset in an AWS S3 object version listing is to iterate over the first X entries, discard them, and then only return the requested entries. This is a limitation of the API from whence I last worked on this code (3 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StartAfter` for offset I think, but you'll need a key from which to start to offset. For that, get some 100 items, and record the ID of the last one. Then you can start off from that ID using the `StartAfter`. It's not perfect but it's the best there is.

```js
// 1) get items
  const { Contents, IsTruncated } = await s3.listObjectsV2({
    Bucket
    MaxKeys: 100,
  }).promise()
// 2) remember last key
  const last = Contents[Contents.length-1].Key
// 3) query via StartFrom
  const { Contents } = await s3.listObjectsV2({
    Bucket,
    MaxKeys: 100,
    StartAfter: last,
  }).promise()
```